# scapy sniff and decode diameter

Tags: python, decode, scapy

I am trying to do scapy/python sniffer for Diameter messages and parse Diameter part to get AVP's from Raw.load.
After some fails I get back to basic python/scapy script like this:

```
from scapy.all import *

def pkt_diam(pkt):
    raw = pkt.getlayer(Raw).load
    print raw
    # pkt.show()

sniff(iface="eth0", filter="port 3868", store=0, prn=pkt_diam)
```

By printing raw.load I have received just some AVP's but very unreadable. If I use

```
pkt.show()
```

I receive whole packet, Ethernet, IP, TCP and Raw part but Raw.load is almost unusable.

```
###[ Raw ]###
        load      = '\x01\x00\x00\xec@\x00\x01/\x01\x00\x00\x00\x07K\x12\xca\x07K\x12\xca\x00\x00\x01\x07@\x00\x00 00000001;000001;61de2650\x00\x00\x01\x04@\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x01\n@\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00(\xaf\x00\x00\x01\x02@\x00\x00\x0c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x15@\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\x08@\x00\x00\x1dtest.a-server.org\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01(@\x00\x00\x14a-server.org\x00\x00\x01)@\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x01\n@\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00(\xaf\x00\x00\x01*@\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x13\x89\x00\x00\x02t\x80\x00\x008\x00\x00(\xaf\x00\x00\x01\n@\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00(\xaf\x00\x00\x02u\x80\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00(\xaf\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02v\x80\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00(\xaf\x00\x00\x00\x05'
```

I need some help to parse and decode Diameter Raw.load message.
Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is to [define the Diameter header yourself](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/build_dissect.html), following the link that I just gave you which is the section of the main Scapy documentation that details the step-by-step guide on how to build your own protocol type (header).

Once you have the Diameter() header defined correctly, dissecting the Diameter packets will become a breeze.

The [wikipedia page on the Diameter protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter_%28protocol%29) seems to be a very good reference regarding the Diameter packet header.

Comment: defining Diameter header by myself would be enough to see Diameter message?

Comment: I have tried to define Diameter header like you suggested but did not work. I guess I did it wrong and i was not able to see Diameter within scapy shell with "ls()". Should i post a new question or paste my definition here?

Comment: @user1627588 I think it's best to update your question to show that you have tried implementing the header yourself. Please do show your Python code that defines the Diameter header(). If you do pkt = Ether() / IP() / TCP() / Diameter(), then do pkt.show(), does it show a packet that is similar to a real Diameter packet? It should just be a matter of getting the fields correctly defined, one by one.

Comment: once again thx man. Of course i'm going to try myself. I am going through links you send me in first answer and I am so far making some progress seems to me. If i got stocked i will update my question of course with code

Answer (score 0):

As part of the current Scapy pull requests https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/pull-requests/ , number #109 provides support for the Diameter layer (parsing and generation).

Download the latest Scapy sources and the diameter.py file which should be placed in the 'contribution' directory (this file will not fully work with the current 2.3.1 Scapy version)

Comment: Looks promising, can you show sample output (your answer doesn't say if the patch you link would provide more readable output than what OP gets)?

Answer (score 0):

scapy is very useful.

```
from scapy.all import *

packets = rdpcap('/path/to/rx.pcap')

def generatePacket(): 
 '''
   Generate a packet.
 '''
 IP()/TCP()/DiamG()

def dissectPacket():
 '''
   dissect a packet.
 '''
 packet[0][DiamG]
```

The above shows the idea. and you can use `print(repr(packet[0][DiamG]))` to see result. Of course in order to check the packet is a Diameter packet, you might want to check at first like:

```
x = packet[0]
while x.payload:
    x = x.payload
    if x.name == 'Diameter' # it has diameter message.
        # dissect it like above.
```

And how to ensemble and send a Diameter packet, one can check:
[building diameter message](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/44d3e8646fd09f1ba82c1c886b05d8ce249c364a/scapy/contrib/diameter.uts)

Comment: Correct. Remember to `load_contrib(“diameter”)` or `from scapy.contrib.diameter import *` to import the diameter module. Also it’s cleaner to use `DiamG in x` then `x[DiamG]` rather than the while loop)